# UWP. How to open multiple videos

Tags: uwp, mediaplayerelement

How to play all files in a folder. This feature does not work correctly:

```
    FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder != null)
    {
        fileList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = 2;
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play(); // <-?? (only the last file in folder)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. Do you want to add multiple videos into a playlist for the `MediaplayerElement` then play them one by one? Or you want to open these videos at the same time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
    int ind;
    private StorageFolder folder = null;
    private IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = null;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_VideoFrameEndedAsync;
    }


    private async void MediaPlayer_VideoFrameEndedAsync(object sender, object args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            ind++;
            if (ind < fileList.Count)
            {
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(fileList[ind]);
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = 2;
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
                notify.Text = fileList[ind].DisplayName;
            }
        });
    }

    private async void folder_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (folder != null)
        {
            fileList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
            if (fileList.Count > 0)
            {
                ind = 0;
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(fileList[ind]);
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = 2;
                mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play(); // <-?? (only the last file in folder)
                notify.Text = fileList[ind].DisplayName;
            }

            //foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
            //{
            //    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
            //    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = 2;
            //    mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play(); // <-?? (only the last file in folder)

            //    notify.Text = file.DisplayName;
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            notify.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.